# Referencing Flash Professional Object in Flash Builder Actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder

I am new to working with Flash Builder and Flash Professional. I have a movie clip called `myplayer` that I created in Flash Professional, and I am trying to code some ActionScript for it in Flash Builder that will change its position on the stage, but I keep getting the following error: TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. at level_1()

Here's the code:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class level_1 extends MovieClip
    {
        public function level_1()
        {
            myplayer.x=650;
            myplayer.y=350;
        }
    }
}
```

I know I am missing something, but I'm not sure what. Any advice?

Comment: Does a MovieClip exist on the stage with a instance name `myplayer`?

Comment: Yes. It exists in the second scene. Would it make a difference if the object is in the second rather than the first scene?

Comment: Here, `level_1` symbol probably needs linkage - there are two symbols in play: `level_1` which references `myplayer`.

Comment: Jason, how would I create that linkage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two symbols here: `level_1` and `myplayer`.  Naming convention for classes usually start with a capital letter; so, I'm going to refer to these types as `Level1` and `MyPlayer`.

So, here's the scene:

- `Level1` is your game level
- `MyPlayer` instance is a child of `Level1`

[image: scene]

The player of this level needs an instance name defined as `myplayer`.

`myplayer` is an instance of the `MyPlayer` class (ActionScript linkage).

[image: player]

Now from Flash Builder, our `Level1` class may manipulate the child `myplayer` instance:

```
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Level1 extends MovieClip {

        public var myplayer:MyPlayer;

        public function Level1() {
            super();

            myplayer.x = 650;
            myplayer.y = 350;
        }
    }
}
```

Flash CS5 example source code with `Level1` ActionScript class at: http://labs.jasonsturges.com/stack-overflow/examples/referencing-flash-professional-object-in-flash-builder/

Comment: Thanks so much, Jason, for your detailed and helpful answer! It was right on the money. Thanks for your help too, Marty.